# Change date helper language Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, date, helper

I'm using Codeigniter for display dates.

I have this but it's echoed in english, how do I set it to other language? I already have the spanish language pack, but I can't figure it out how to load it.

```
 $this->load->helper('date');
 echo mdate("%F %d, %Y", strtotime(now()));
```

Thanks

Comment: Did the below work out for you? Btw if you want the month name to be capitalized just put the entire `strftime()` inside `ucfirst()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Set locale to Spanish Argentina, change to your installed language
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_AR');

echo strftime("%B %d, %Y", time());
```

First you do not need to use the date helper to accomplish this. `mdate()` is essentially the same as `strftime()` where just the vars are slightly different. Also your code `strtotime(now())` is wrong. `now()` is the exact same as `time()` as indicated in the CI documentation. It returns a UNIX timestamp, `strtotime()` converts a string to a UNIX timestamp. So what you were doing was trying to convert a timestamp to a timestamp, which of course is wrong. I changed the code so it doesn't require the helper and correctly will output `MONTHNAME DATE, YEAR` in the specified language. Make sure you change the `es_AR` to whatever Spanish language you installed. It will be the in the format `es_COUNTRYCODE`

Answer (score 0):

The traductions dates in "calendar_lang.php"

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'spanish');
$this->load->library('calendar');
echo 'Mes:'.$this->calendar->get_month_name(date('m'));
echo 'Día:'.$this->calendar->get_day_names(date('d'));
```